# Flex 3: removing items from an array collection when the user clicks a button and reflecting that in a repeater

Tags: apache-flex, arraycollection, dataprovider

I have an arrayCollection with the following structure:

```
projectErrorsAC
    0
        project1number
        project2number
        position1number
        position2number
        project1name
        project2name
        student
    1
        ...
```

the AC is defined as follows:

```
[Bindable] private var projectErrorsAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
```

I'm using this AC in a repeater to display each error.  After each error is shown, I've placed an "Accept" and "Deny" button.  Once the user clicks either one of these buttons, I'd like to call a function that removes the particular error from the AC.  Here's what I have so far:

Repeater:

```
<mx:Repeater id="projRP" width="100%" dataProvider="{projectErrorsAC}">
<mx:HBox>
    <mx:Text id="projmsg" text="{projRP.currentItem.student} is working on the following projects on the same day: {projRP.currentItem.proj1name} and {projRP.currentItem.proj2name}." />
    <mx:Text id="allow" text="Allow" color="#ff0000" selectable="false" 
        click="acceptProjConflict(projRP.currentItem);" 
        mouseOver="parentApplication.switchCursor(true);" 
        mouseOut="parentApplication.switchCursor(false);" />
    <mx:Text text=" |" />
    <mx:Text id="decline" text="Decline" color="#ff0000" selectable="false" click="declineProjConflict(projRP.currentItem);" mouseOver="parentApplication.switchCursor(true);" mouseOut="parentApplication.switchCursor(false);" />
</mx:HBox>
</mx:Repeater>
```

and here's the function I'm calling in the "click" part:

```
public function acceptProjConflict(conflict:Object):void
{
for (var i:int = 0; i < projectErrorsAC.length; i++)
{
    if (projectErrorsAC.getItemAt(i) == conflict)
        projectErrorsAC.removeItemAt(i);
}               
}
```

for some reason, this isn't working...

*** EDIT ***

SUCCESS!

I had to create a module to put inside the repeater - the repeater now looks like this:

```
<mx:Repeater id="projRP" width="100%" dataProvider="{projectErrorsAC}">
    <conflict:showErrors id="projErrors" thisObject="{projRP.currentItem}" isProject="true"/>
</mx:Repeater>
```

and my module looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init();">
        <mx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                public var isProject:Boolean;
                public var thisObject:Object;
                [Bindable] public var displayString:String = new String;

                private function init():void
                {
                    if (isProject)
                    {
                        displayString = thisObject.student + " is working on the following projects on the same day: " + thisObject.proj1name + " and " + thisObject.proj2name + ".";
                    }
                }
            ]]>
        </mx:Script>

    <mx:Canvas width="750">
        <mx:HBox>
            <mx:Text id="projmsg" text="{displayString}" />
            <mx:Text id="allow" text="Allow" color="#ff0000" selectable="false" click="parentDocument.acceptProjConflict(thisObject)" mouseOver="parentApplication.switchCursor(true);" mouseOut="parentApplication.switchCursor(false);" />
            <mx:Text text=" |" />
            <mx:Text id="decline" text="Decline" color="#ff0000" selectable="false" click="parentDocument.declineProjConflict(thisObject);" mouseOver="parentApplication.switchCursor(true);" mouseOut="parentApplication.switchCursor(false);" />
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Module>
```

Comment: How exactly isn't it working? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be an ArrayCollection specific issue that is being caused because it might occur that you are trying to remove an object that is no longer at the index you think it might be.
I believe this kind of problem is exactly why Java advises the use of collection iterators.

Further explanation [here](http://form-function.blogspot.com/2008/03/removing-items-from-array-collection.html)

Furthermore, I would advise you to use List with an itemRenderer instead of a repeater. Repeaters are known for their ability to cause memory leaks and are not as optimized as a List with itemRenderers.

Cheers

Comment: I don't think it's an ArrayCollection issue, but I do agree with using List instead of Repeater.

Comment: @J_A_X Does the `DataGroup` component address the problems the `Repeater` has?

Comment: ^ What he said.  DataGroup is the bestest :D

Comment: Okay, i can understand that a leak might cause the item not to be in the place it was before... but my acceptProjConflict function compares the repeater.currentItem to every item in the renderer and then, when they match, it removes that matched item.

Answer (score 0):

First, have you tried debugging?

Second, I'm surprised the click handler works because Repeater has weird scoping issues (which normally fails silently), which is why I said you should try to debug.

Third, your click handler is inefficient, you should do something like this instead:

```
public function acceptProjConflict(conflict:Object):void
{
   for(var i:uint, len:uint = projectErrorsAC.length; i<len; i++)
   {
       if(projectErrorsAC.source[i] == conflict)
       {
           projectErrorsAC.removeItemAt(i);
           break;
       }
   }         
}
```

But yeah, fairly sure your problem lies with the fact that your handler is never called.

Comment: removeItem isn't a valid method

Comment: Oh sorry, I was thinking ArrayList.  Updated to reflect ArrayCollection, but my point remains that you should use the debugger since your handler probably doesn't even gets called.  Actually, now that I think of it, your repeater doesn't work at all since the 'currentItem' is just used as an iterator, not a data provider which will become null at the end of the repeat.  This will fail every time.  Just use a List instead.

Comment: Yeah, i tried putting in a simple "Alert.show("HI");" for the first line of the function... never pops up. 

This is most likely going to consume the rest of my day (4.5 more hours) lol

Comment: Anybody have a link to an example of a list that might help me out?  I'm pretty new at Flex.  I tried googling it, but can't connect the dots between the examples ive found and what i'm trying to do.

Comment: If you're new to Flex, why are you using Flex 3? ewwww.  [Get with the times](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+4).  And then while you're using Flex 4, you can use [DataGroup to do exactly what you need](http://www.hufkens.net/2009/06/flex-4-datagroup-and-itemrenderers/).

Comment: is flex 4 free for people with a @edu email address like flex 3 is?

Comment: Flex is free for everyone.  I think what you're talking about is Flash Builder, the IDE, which should still be free for education.

Answer (score 0):

You might use

```
[Bindable] private var projectErrorsAC:ArrayCollection = [];
```

instead of

```
[Bindable] private var projectErrorsAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
```

It will be faster when you have large data.